# select2.min.js not overlapping the original select obejct

Tags: html, jsp, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I did something like

```
sample_product_parent.find(".select").select2();
```

and the select2 dropdown did not overlap the original select object.
Making it look like that there are 2 dropdowns.
What needs to be included?
Thanks!

Screenshot:
[image: See screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that CSS property `position` for your select element is not **relative** but **absolute**.
Change it to relative to see if it will overlapping by select2 UI normally. If yes, but your element is placed in not right place, than you need to recompose your HTML layout.

Comment: My other fields are OK. I did not do anything different to that one